# jenssegers/laravel-mongodb regex in where not working

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb

I'm working on a Laravel API with a MongoDB database using [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

I'm trying to make a filter to get some particular data using a regex. In the tutorial for this plugin I found this:

```
User::where('name', 'regex', new MongoRegex("/.*doe/i"))->get();
```

So my code looks like this:

```
School::where('name', 'regex', new MongoRegex("/haags/i"))->get();
```

But the result is empty. When I output the query it looks like this:

```
db.schools.find({"name":{"$regex":{"regex":"haags","flags":"i"}}})
```

And when I use that query in the console it says:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $regex has to be a string",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

I also tried:

```
School::where('name', 'regexp', "/haags/i")->get();
```

But that gave me this query:

```
db.schools.find({"name":{"$regex":"\/haag\/i"}})
```

which apparently escapes the forward slash and makes the regex invalid. And besides that, a regex should not be between quotes or it should be something like this (found in the MongoDB manual):

```
db.products.find( { description: { $regex: /^S/, $options: 'm' } } )
```

So there is a problem in the conversion to MongoDB query or I'm doing something wrong. Can someone please tell me what it is?

Comment: Do you had a solution for your problem ? I have the same ;-) Thanks

Comment: I stopped working with mongoDB and moved on, there were just too many issues...

Comment: 2016-07-31 - Same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue :
It is actually siuated in the function compileWhereBasic in class Builder.

When the where condition has 3 parameters, the middle operator is appended in the front

Like {$regexp => { $regexp : "a", $options : "i"}} The first "$regexp" is the operator being apended. However this is not the case for = (already managed properly) and regexp **that should not be appended.**

Correction is like this :

```
if (! isset($operator) or in_array($operator, ['=','regex']) ) {
        $query = [$column => $value];
    } elseif (array_key_exists($operator, $this->conversion)) {
        $query = [$column => [$this->conversion[$operator] => $value]];
    } else {
        $query = [$column => ['$' . $operator => $value]];
    }
```

Instead of original code :

```
if (! isset($operator) or $operator == '=') {
        $query = [$column => $value];
    } elseif (array_key_exists($operator, $this->conversion)) {
        $query = [$column => [$this->conversion[$operator] => $value]];
    } else {
        $query = [$column => ['$' . $operator => $value]];
    }
```

Hope that helps !